# Position sticky not working on mobile version

Tags: html, css, mobile, navbar, mobile-website

I have some problem, position:sticky is working normally on a browser on a computer, but unfortunately it doesn’t work on mobile version, menu which I created with that setup still is on it’s place, I couldn’t find anywhere any answer about my problem.

```css
header {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: the code is ok, work on mobile (i try with inspect). which device you tested? have you a live version?

Comment: Which mobile browser(s) are you testing on? On which platforms? With which HTML?